# Trying to save same data to firebase using spring boot

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore, spring-restcontroller

I get this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize object. Serializing Collections is not supported, please use Lists instead (found in field 'user.subsMsg')
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper.serializeError(CustomClassMapper.java:555) ~[google-cloud-firestore-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
```

When trying to add data to firebase.

This is the postrequest:

```
@PostMapping("/pollAdd")
    public String pollAdd(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String description, @RequestParam String isPublic,
            @RequestParam String status, Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
        Optional<User> userOpt = userRepository.findById(main.getUser(client));
        if (!userOpt.isPresent()) {
            return "index";
        }
        User user = userOpt.get();
        model.addAttribute("name", getUserName(authentication));
        Poll newPoll = new Poll();
        if(description.isBlank() && name.isBlank()) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Fill all attributes and try again!");
            return "pollCreate";
        }
        newPoll.setDescription(description);
        newPoll.setName(name);
        newPoll.setPublic(Boolean.parseBoolean(isPublic));
        newPoll.setStatus(status);
        newPoll.setUser(user);
        pollRepository.save(newPoll);
        CollectionReference pollCR = fb.getFirebase().collection("Polls");
        pollCR.document(String.valueOf(newPoll.getPollID())).set(newPoll);  #This is where the problem occur.


        model.addAttribute("polls", newPoll);
        model.addAttribute("name", getUserName(authentication));
        return "index";
    }
```

And this is the poll class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Poll {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    private int pollID;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private boolean isPublic;
    private int voteGreen;
    private int voteRed;
    private String status;
    private int timeLimit;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<User> usersVoted = new ArrayList<>();

    public Poll() {
    }

    public Poll(String name, String description, boolean isPublic, int voteGreen, int voteRed, String status,
            int timeLimit, User user) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.isPublic = isPublic;
        this.voteGreen = voteGreen;
        this.voteRed = voteRed;
        this.status = status;
        this.timeLimit = timeLimit;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setUsersVoted(User userVoted) {
        this.usersVoted.add(userVoted);
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        if (user != null)
            user.setPolls(this);
    }

    public void setVoteRed(int red) {
        this.voteRed += red;
    }

    public void setVoteGreen(int green) {
        this.voteGreen += green;
    }

    public void setPublic(boolean isPublic) {
        this.isPublic = isPublic;
    }

}
```

I am trying to add the same data that I add to the H2 database into the firebase database at the same time. How can I go about doing this? Is this wrong? I have tried adding @IgnoreExtraProperties to my class and also @Exclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is self explanatory and you can find many other cases like this all over Stack Overflow. You can for example convert your collection to a list by using `Collections.singletonList()`